# How to handle jqxgrid export to excel error gracefully?

Tags: jquery, excel, jqxgrid

I am using `jqxgrid` to get the grid data exported in excel . When I filter the grid and if there is matching item for that filter option , the grid  shows up empty as expected . But then , when I try to export the empty grid to excel by clicking on a button (let the button id be `eXButton`), I get a firebug error `There is no data that can be exported`.

Currently I am trying to have the `eXButton` disabled if the grid is empty(either because data has not come from server or because filtering has been applied due to which grid shows no data) . But , I am not able to find out which grid method or functionality I can use to achieve that .

Any help will be deeply appreciated here .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jqxgrid API method `getrows()`:

> Gets all rows. Returns an array of all rows loaded in the Grid. If the Grid is filtered, the returned value is an array of the filtered records.

So you can take the `length` of this returned array to either enable or disable your button.

Comment: I have used getrows() . It returns the no of rows in the grid . That's not of any help . Whether you filter a grid or not, it will always contain the pre- existing no of elements . Filtering does not make the elements disappear.

Comment: Which kind of source configuration do you have? (local array, remote data or even virtual mode)? It probably depends on that.